# RubyOnRails 7 redirection protection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I want to redirect out of the application like this:

```
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    @customer.save
    redirect_to "https://www.shoptet.cz/", allow_other_host: true
  end
```

ROR 7 have integrated redirect protection so I am using, allow_other_host: true as they say in the documentation and it's not working anyway, no error executed just nothing happed...
here is Server log:

```
Started POST "/customers" for 89.24.40.97 at 2022-08-20 21:38:41 +0200
Cannot render console from 89.24.40.97! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
Processing by CustomersController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "customer"=>{"name"=>"jirkanovakneda@seznam.cz", "heslo"=>"hahshjsueb28"}, "commit"=>"Přihlášení"}
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:25:in `create'
  Customer Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "customers" ("name", "heslo", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "jirkanovakneda@seznam.cz"], ["heslo", "hahshjsueb28"], ["created_at", "2022-08-20 19:38:41.917978"], ["updated_at", "2022-08-20 19:38:41.917978"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:25:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (12.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:25:in `create'
Redirected to https://www.shoptet.cz/
Completed 302 Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 12.8ms | Allocations: 2081)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happened"?

Comment: Your request is being processed as TURBO_STREAM, check if that's the problem. Processing it as HTML works as expected, the redirect happens.

Comment: I wasn't redirected, just stayed on the same site without redirect, ill try to disable turbo that's a good idea thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for help, problem fixed by disabling turbo on the button:

```rb
data: {turbo: false}
```

Comment: Just to know, how were you making that request to be processed as turbo_stream?

Comment: It is processed as turbo_stream by default in our projects, i dont know if its default settings in Rails 7 or it is inside of our company template